# Adding Javascript to custom HTML

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, joomla2.5, contact-form

I really cant figure this out, and have spend much time searching for the answer, but nothing have worked..

I have created a contant page in Joomla "Custom HMTL" module, using form and php, and i want to make a function that checks if the fields are correct and the typed emal is a valid email. If not i want a alert message to be showed.

I have tryed using php and javascript. I think my javascript works fine, but dossent seem to work with the "Custom HTML" module for Joomla.

Does any one know how to add Javascript? or is there an easier way to do this?
Iam using JCE editor and Joomla 2.5

```
    function validate_form(thisform) {

     var v1 = document.getElementsByName('name');
     if (v1.value < '!') {
         alert('Feltet navn skal udfyldes');
         v1.focus();
         return false;
     }

     var regex = new RegExp('^[\\w-_\.+]*[\\w-_\.]\@([\\w]+\\.)+[\\w]+[\\w]$');
     if (!regex.test(thisform.mail.value)) {
         alert("Email-adressen indeholder ugyldige tegn\r\nEller er på anden måde ikke korrekt udfyldt");
         thisform.mail.focus();
         return (false);
     }

     var v2 = document.getElementsByName('message');
     if (v2.value < '!') {
         alert('Feltet beskrivelse skal udfyldes');
         v2.focus();
         return false;
     }
 }
 </script>

 <form action="http://test.webkjaer.dk/templates/tilbud.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)">
    <table style="width: 575px;" border="0" align="left">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Navn <span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span> 
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                </td>
                <td>E-mail <span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span> 
                    <input type="text" name="email" / >
                </td>
```

...

Comment: There are a lot of validation plugins for Jquery available that are really easy to use, you should check those... And... YOu missed a closing > on the last input.

Comment: Hi.
Any suggestions for plugins? The closing tag is a typing mistake, it is included in the original code.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ is one of the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best off making it a proper module rather than adding all your code into a custom module and setting the action to a raw php file. This is bad coding standards when using Joomla and in some cases can pose security threats.

I suggest you look into Module Development on the Joomla Docs:

http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Development

You may also want to save yourself a little time and use a Module Generator which will generate the core files for the module and XML details, so all you have to do it start on the functionality:

http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras/module-generator.html

As for adding importing Javascript code, you will want to use the JFactory::getDocument(); method. I'll show you an example below:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument;

$js = 'var v1 = document.getElementsByName('name');
       if (v1.value < '!') {
          alert('Feltet navn skal udfyldes');
          v1.focus();
          return false;
       }';
$document->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for taking time answering my question. The first part regarding security i get, but i dont get the getDocument(); method, iam pretty much new to php and javascript, so the syntax is still very stranged for me.
Do i still need a onsubmit event or what?

Comment: you can use `onsubmit` if you want. If you're new to PHP then I would recommend downloading a form extension from [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org), looking at the code and editing it. the getDcoument(); code I showed you is used to add custom Javascript into the <head> tags using Joomla coding standards ([read more](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScriptDeclaration))